# How do I split a string of 8 numbers and access each of them individually?

Tags: java, arrays

I have written my program to get input from the user in the form of a string consisting of 8 numbers. I want to split the 8 numbers so I can access each of them individually. Is it kind of the same as Python where I'd use input[1] or so to access them, also how do I split them?

I'm not sure what way to go about it.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input;
System.out.println("Please type your number in 8 bit binary form: ");
input = sc.nextLine();
```

The code runs fine so far, just don't know how to split the input into an array of 8 different numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: 8 numbers (`10 20 30 4 55 6 777 8888`) or 8 digits (`12435687`)?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger The code says "8 bit binary form", so something like "10010010".

Comment: @Tom title and text says "8 numbers" so something like `"10 20 30 4 55 6 777 8888"` - I think it is wise to ask **OP** for what is really meant and not just guess something

Answer (score 0):

You could try something as simple as that!

```java
for (char vl:input.toCharArray()){
  System.out.println(vl);
}
```

The question is what are your split restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [charAt() function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) to get values sequentially for all characters in the string.

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
String[] array = input.split(""); //split your string into string array using regex to define delimiter
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); //initialize array of numbers
    for (String s: array) {
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(s)); // parse each string as Integer value
    }
```

So u will have numbers array, then you can access each number by it's index.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this

```
String[] binaryArray = input.split("");
```